# Visit USA with current Canadian PR and US B1/B2 obtained from India earlier

Tags: usa, canada, india

I am an immigrant to Canada on PR and has visited US earlier from India on Visit visa valid for 10 years. I would now like to visit USA again from Canada for short stay of 3 days. What documents would i need to travel?

Answer (score 3):

Your passport and visa should be sufficient.